# How to configure pom.xml so deploy custom artifact to remote repo (archiva)

Tags: maven, deployment, archiva

How do I deploy an artifact into my archva repository? I want to configure my pom.xml to do this but I'm not sure how to set the groupdId and artifactId and version.

I'm under the impression this artifact must first be copied to my local repo via the install phase. How does it then get deployed to my archiva repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here - http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/userguide/deploy.html Archiva have a nice guide, explaining how to deploy your artifact into it.

I hope it will help.